# Retrieve & Run a JS file stored in AWS S3 from Node app

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I'm building an auto-grader Node app hosted on AWS. Here is a quick overview of the desired functionality:

1. Student uploads file.js to AWS s3 (file.js contains exports)
2. App retrieves that file using AWS-SDK Node module (to verify successful upload before grading)
3. App uses the class exported in retrieved file.js to run unit tests (I plan to use a module to export the results of unit tests)

Steps 1 and 2 are working fine. I receive the following info from the console when i retrieve the file:

```
{ Key: 'student-submissions/assignment-1/user1-a1.js',
  LastModified: 2020-07-23T23:03:37.000Z,
  ETag: '"cniw3e4bvo6wyb7oef80y23b83g28f7g328y"',
  Size: 69,
  StorageClass: 'STANDARD',
  Owner:
   { ID:
      '782hfiow48f9fh49f40y8b20fb203byf83b02bf02bf308b308fb2380fb' } }
```

My question is this: **can I instantiate the class export contained in file.js, and then pass that class into my test class without saving the file?** This is what I have in mind:

```
s3.listObjects(bucketParams, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  } else {
    const FileClass = require(data.Contents[0]); // problem line #1
    const fc = new FileClass();                  // problem line #2
    const A1Tests = require('./my-tests/a1.test.js');
    const a1Tester = new A1Tests(fc);
    a1Tester.run();
  }
});
```

Is this possible? If not, community insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Basically you have to use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) ([Never use eval!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!)). I assume you run code from students generally... how do you ring fence that for the slightly more skilled, let's say less will intentioned students?

Comment: ah- that is interesting. i never thought of it like that. Thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with, though there is a potential security risk with running the code. It could lead to the execution of malicious software, but this is what I was told to do. There is a good amount of trust involved with this implementation:

```
var requireFromUrl = require('require-from-url/sync');
s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', signedUrlParams, function (err, url) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('error', err);
    } else {    
        /* Solution */
        const assignment = requireFromUrl(url)
        const ts = new TestSuite();
        ts.evaluate(assignment);
    }
});
```

Rather than pulling the object, I retrieved the a signed URL. As you can probably tell, I utilized the [require-from-url](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-from-url) package.

Also, here is an idea of the file being accessed via URL:

```
const alwaysFalse = () => false;

module.exports = {
  alwaysFalse
};
```